# chemfig: how to align the arrows of different schemes?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, chemfig

I am trying to get the arrows of three different schemes aligned but would like to have text in between them, as you can see below.

Despite searching for hours, i haven't found a solution..

```
\documentclass[a4paper,pdftex,ngerman,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setatomsep{1.5em}
\setcrambond{1.5ex}{1pt}{2pt}

\begin{document}
\noindent \textbf{Cracken von Seitenketten in Aromaten:} 

\schemestart
\chemfig{**6([:-150]-----(-C_4H_9)-)} 
\arrow
\chemfig{**6([:-150]-----(-C_2H_5)-)} \arrow{0}[,0]\+ \chemfig{H_2C=CH_2}
\schemestop
\newline\newline

\noindent \textbf{Dealkylierung:} 

\schemestart
\chemfig{**6([:-150]-----(-C_2H_5)-)} 
\arrow
\chemfig{**6([:-150]------)}\arrow{0}[,0] \+ \chemfig{H_2C=CH_2}
\schemestop
\newline\newline

\noindent \textbf{Cracken von Olefinen:} 
\newline

\schemestart
\chemfig{CH_3-[:150]-[:-150]-[:150]-[:-150]=[:150]-[:-150]H_3C} 
\arrow
\chemfig{CH_3-[:-150]=[:150]-[:-150]H_3C} \arrow{0}[,0]\+ \chemfig{CH_3-[:150]=[:-150]H_3C}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image: the current result]

Comment: is this altogether supposed to be one figure (with a common caption) or rather part of running text like several math equations?

Comment: I would rather have it as a part of a running text, because i would like to add text below the headings. If its only possible as one figure, that would be fine, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure there is a more elegant way, but a crude approach is to calculate the difference in width between each of the smaller left compounds (the first two) and the largest (the last) and add that as `\hspace` before the start of the smaller reactions. Showing each step:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,pdftex,ngerman,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setatomsep{1.5em}
\setcrambond{1.5ex}{1pt}{2pt}

\begin{document}
%Width of first
\newlength\lenfirst
\settowidth\lenfirst{\chemfig{**6([:-150]-----(-C_4H_9)-)}}
%Width of second
\newlength\lensecond
\settowidth\lensecond{\chemfig{**6([:-150]-----(-C_2H_5)-)}}
%Width of third
\newlength\lenthird
\settowidth\lenthird{\chemfig{CH_3-[:150]-[:-150]-[:150]-[:-150]=[:150]-[:-150]H_3C}}

%Difference for first
\newlength\lendelfirst
\setlength\lendelfirst{\lenthird}
\addtolength\lendelfirst{-\lenfirst}

%Difference for the second
\newlength\lendelsecond
\setlength\lendelsecond{\lenthird}
\addtolength\lendelsecond{-\lensecond}    

\noindent \textbf{Cracken von Seitenketten in Aromaten:} 

\hspace{\lendelfirst}\schemestart
\chemfig{**6([:-150]-----(-C_4H_9)-)} 
\arrow
\chemfig{**6([:-150]-----(-C_2H_5)-)} \arrow{0}[,0]\+ \chemfig{H_2C=CH_2}
\schemestop
\newline\newline

\noindent \textbf{Dealkylierung:} 

\hspace{\lendelsecond}\schemestart
\chemfig{**6([:-150]-----(-C_2H_5)-)} 
\arrow
\chemfig{**6([:-150]------)}\arrow{0}[,0] \+ \chemfig{H_2C=CH_2}
\schemestop
\newline\newline

\noindent \textbf{Cracken von Olefinen:} 
\newline

\hspace{0pt}\schemestart
\chemfig{CH_3-[:150]-[:-150]-[:150]-[:-150]=[:150]-[:-150]H_3C} 
\arrow
\chemfig{CH_3-[:-150]=[:150]-[:-150]H_3C} \arrow{0}[,0]\+ \chemfig{CH_3-[:150]=[:-150]H_3C}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image: left-aligned with arrows]